# PHP 7.2 MySQL Google App Engine after login cookie issue

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a simple application that I have downloaded from git installed on one instance of Google App Engine.
https://github.com/ssl/ezXSS

I have a second app engine instance where I followed the phpmyadmin tutorial in the link below to install phpmyadmin to administer my mysql database in google cloud services.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

for the simple app and the phpmyadmin, the app.yaml is pretty much the same

```
service: default
runtime: php72

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  #application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  #application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: auto
  secure: always
  #login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  #login: admin
```

both instances display their initial page fine, but after the submit or login, they both complain about cookies.

my simple app should be writing to the database from the first page but I get this error

```
This page isn’t working
XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

From PHPmyadmin I get

```
There is mismatch between HTTPS indicated on the server and client. This can lead to non working
phpMyAdmin or a security risk. Please fix your server configuration to indicate HTTPS properly.
```

and

```
Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.
```

its not a browser issue.....I have cleared the cookies and data related to these sites.  I have tried in both chrome and firefox with the same result.

I am using App Engine standard environment for both app engine instance.

both instances, the initial pages are showing as secure.....
the simple app after submitting says its not secure when it returns the message about the cookie

**edit:**

after further investigation it appears I am making a connection with the mysql database, both using PDO and mysqli. But I can't seem to do much more than make a connection. getAttribute for PDO seems to be about the only thing that works.
If I make a fetch or a query it fails, though the same fetch or query in the google cloud shell using the same user works fine.

Seems like a GAE or php or mysql config issue?

Comment: Could you please share with us the first application that you've downloaded from Git? Taking a look at the code might help us spot what might be wrong. Could you please elaborate more on what you want to achieve with the first and second applications?

Comment: https://github.com/ssl/ezXSS

Comment: For ezXSS what appears to be happening is that when it logins in, it doesn't return the PHP session ID or the CSRF token.  At least I think that is what is happening.  it seems like somewhere in User.php, within the login function......that csrf doesn't get returned or is lost.  I think that csrf should be set to the cookie.  either in User.php - public function login($password, $code) or in Request.php - private function convert($array)

Comment: hmmmm, I thought it was the applications that were the problem but turns out its likely something to do with the database setup.  'textPayload: "2019-12-17T05:10:25.905630Z 13958 [Note] Aborted connection 13958 to db: 'ezxss' user: 'ezxss' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (Got an error reading communication packets)"' '  I also realized that its not actually writing anything to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize there was an ability to see the GAE php logs, so that I could see what was failing.

I finally managed to get some basic sql working and then tested the table creation that ezxss was trying to perform, and it turned out it wasn't working and wasn't throwing an error.

Though it would throw an error if I pasted into cloud shell.... complaining about ENGINE=MyISAM

so this code

```
$this->database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`setting` varchar(500) NOT NULL,`value` text NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;');

$this->database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`shareid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,`cookies` text,`dom` longtext,`origin` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`referer` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`uri` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`user-agent` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,`time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`archive` int(11) DEFAULT 0,`screenshot` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,`localstorage` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL, `sessionstorage` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;');
```

got changed to

```
$this->database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`setting` varchar(500) NOT NULL,`value` text NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;');

$this->database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`shareid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,`cookies` text,`dom` longtext,`origin` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`referer` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`uri` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`user-agent` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,`ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,`time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`archive` int(11) DEFAULT 0,`screenshot` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,`localstorage` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL, `sessionstorage` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;');
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine) you mentioned and I was able to deploy successfully phpmyadmin in App Engine Standard.
However I did face some issues getting the blowfish secret key for the config.inc.php file. The tutorial sends you [here](http://www.question-defense.com/tools/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator) to get the key but I got nothing, only the example key. So, I used [this other website](https://phpsolved.com/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator/) to get the key.

Some other things you could check are if your Cloud SQL Instance is a 2nd generation instance, php runtime (I used php55).

Mmmm forgot to mention that I deployed phpmyadmin as my first service(default) within App Engine. So, you might also want to try that, creating new project, new app engine  and deploy phpmyadmin as your first service.

Comment: Thanks for the response Antonio.  I seem to be able to connect to my database with mysqli and PDO in php.......and with PDO I can acquire attributes using the get Attribute(), but it won't let me read or write to the database.  so basically fetch and query don't work. 'echo $dbh->fetch('SELECT * FROM settings WHERE setting = "timezone"');' doesn't work. But in the cloud shell this works without any problem using the same user. I am using php72.